# Weird case, only internet working, calls and messages are stopped

Tags: sms, calls, connection-issues, mobile-network, motorola

My mobile is Moto G4 Play and has a Jio Reliance SIM in it. I am receiving full mobile networks and I am able to browse internet. But, I cannot receive any calls and messages. I cannot make any call and send any messages. I have a custom ROM installed. My mobile was working fine 2 days ago. But, when I remove the SIM and inserted it again, the problem starts as I mentioned above.

My settings are mobile data enabled, roaming enabled, VoLTE enabled (enhanced 4G LTE mode), network automatic select network, and jionet APN.

[image]

I inserted this SIM into another device and was working fine. I also did a factory reset but didn't work. And when I make a call, my mobile networks are lost and come back again. I also installed Jio 4g Voice app but am still not able able to make calls. If someone tries to call me, my mobile is called as switched off. I also changed the SIM slot but nothing was solved. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: "when I make a call, my mobile networks are lost and come back again" this is a clear indicator that VoLTE doesn't work. I assume in your region 3G is no longer available (end of life by MNO), so your phone switches to 2G to make the call and therefore drops mobile network connection. After the cal it switches back to 4G. May be your provider has enabled a VoLTE option that is incompatible with your custom ROM? I would first check `adb logcat` for errors.

Comment: This has nothing to do with my custom rom. Because, before custom rom, my SIM was working fine. Also, after custom rom installed, it was working fine. But, you may be right because 3 days ago VoLTE was showing. But still, there's app called JIO 4gVoice. In this app, you can atleast make VoIP calls. But, this app is not able to connect with my mobile networks.

Comment: One more thing JIO SIM cannot work on 2g or 3g devices. It will only work on 4g.

Comment: Dial *#*#4636#*#* => phone information => drop down menu (top right) => IMS Status => Tell us what's being shown on VoLTE status.

Comment: Problem solved! Don't know what happened. I installed JioCall app on playstore again. And It worked. But earlier this app was trying to connect only. But now it is showing online. But I still don't know what actually happened. I was able to use my sim without this app earlier. I have enhanced 4g Lite Mode which is indirectly a Volte Mode I think. Because in custom rom it is showing Volte Mode.